# Correct batch for csv filter

Tags: batch, csv

I am already write a batch script that filter the values from a particular column of a CSV file one by one and store them in result.csv and the batch code as below.
Say, following is the CSV file:

```
@echo off
(
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-22 delims=%%,. " %%A in ("combined.csv") do (

if %%~C%%~D geq 300 if %%~C%%~D leq 700 if %%E gtr 50 if %%F gtr 100 if %%G gtr 100 echo %%A,%%B,%%C.%%D%%,%%E%%,%%F,%%G%%,%%H.%%I,%%J.%%K,%%L,%%M,%%N.%%O,%%P,%%Q,%%R.%%S,%%T.%%U%%,%%V )

)>>result.csv


:: %%P.%% = 16 = B-QV
:: %%Q.%% = 17 = S-QV
:: %%R.%%S = 18 & 19 = P/E
:: %%T.%%U%% = 20 & 21 = L4Q DY
:: %%V = 22 = Sector
```

I have to filter Chg% 3% to 7%, B% is more than 50%, Trans is more than 100 and and Vol/VMA Chg% (5)is more than 100.

However the last filter where the problem parts where it shows the wrong data especially the Sector because the Sector had data with character(example Telecommunications & Media)  & on it and the B-QV and S-QV sometimes had number XXXXX.X one dot at the end(example 1361794.0).The P/E and L4Q DY had dash – means no data and some times had data. How can I resolved the problem.Can somebody show me the correct batch code?

Here the CSV File that I need to filter:

```
"Code","Stock","Chg%","B%","Trans","Vol/VMA Chg% (5)","Last","VWAP","S-Issued","Trend","Buy","B-QV","S-QV","P/E","L4Q DY","Sector" 
"694724","DIGI-C24","+1200.000%","83%","27","115%","0.065","0.0760","50000000.00","SSSSSSBS","0.055","5500.00","6000.00","-","-","Telecommunications & Media" 
"688837","AXIATA-C37","+100.000%","51%","8","4428%","0.120","0.1236","50000000.00","SBBBBBSB","0.120","6180.00","12500.00","-","-","Telecommunications & Media" 
"694727","DIGI-C27","+90.909%","0%","1","0%","0.105","0.1050","35000000.00","S","0.095","47500.00","50000.00","-","-","Telecommunications & Media" 
"688835","AXIATA-C35","+83.333%","59%","24","978%","0.165","0.1648","35000000.00","SSBSSBBB","0.160","80000.00","82500.00","-","-","Telecommunications & Media" 
"0138","MYEG","+6.429%","60%","2526","124%","1.490","1.4627","3606305993.00","SSBBBBBB","1.490","569776.00","858900.00","26.86","0.34%","Technology"
```

Comment: I have a strong [deja vue](https://superuser.com/questions/1432161/how-to-filter-value-in-csv-with-batch-and-show-the-output-to-txt), why do you create a new user for this? With now double quoted columns the whole approach can't work anymore (splitting at `%,. `). You should resort to using a script language with an understanding of csv files like PowerShell with the `Import-Csv` cmdlet.

Comment: I had the idea to batch process whole lines in a sub routine, but the embedded percent signs in the values prohibit this as cmd interpretes them as variables over column boundaries and the `B%` column simply vanishes. So with your current setup I see no way to process this in batch.